# Does Hazelcast version 3 support RHEL 8

Tags: hazelcast, rhel8

I wanted to know if Hazelcast 3.12.12 supports RHEL 8? From documentation, I can see that Hazelcast version 4 and 5 supports RHEL 8. But, I could not get any information on Hazelcast version 3. Can you please let me know if Hazelcast version 3 can be deployed on RHEL 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the RHEL 8 is supported, but the Hazelcast `3.12.z` itself has already reached its End-of-Life. Check the [Version Support Windows](https://support.hazelcast.com/s/article/Version-Support-Windows) page. It's highly recommended to use a supported version!

That said, the only requirement is to have a supported Java version installed. It would be Java 8 or Java 11 for Hazelcast `3.12.z`.

Check details in the documentation: https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/3.12/getting-started/supported-jvms

Comment: Thanks for the response. As we need time to upgrade Hazelcast in our product, wanted to check the RHEL 8 support on version 3.

Comment: Does Hazelcast support RHEL 9?